# Highlight the highest number in tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I've a simple tableview with numbers in cells. One cell - one number. I want to make cell text bold if the cell number is the highest from other table view cells numbers.

For example, I have a tableview with numbers:

[image]

I need to make the 99 cell text bold as 99 is the highest number in all table view cells. How this can be done?

My DataSource array:

```
class Exercise: NSObject, Codable {
  var name = ""
  var reps = [Count]()
}

class Count: NSObject, Codable {
  var reps: Double
  var date = Date()

    init(reps: Double) {
    self.reps = reps
    super.init()
    }

}
```

And my code:

```
class Counts: UITableViewController, CountsDetailViewControllerDelegate {

var countExercise: Exercise!

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return countExercise.reps.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Count", for: indexPath)

        let item = countExercise.reps[indexPath.row]

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .short
        formatter.timeStyle = .short

        cell.textLabel?.text = item.reps.removeZerosFromEnd()
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = formatter.string(from: item.date)

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: what is your dataSource array ?

Comment: I added to the question.

Comment: Not related to your question but you are creating a new DateFormatter every time cellForRowAt is called

Comment: And what is the better place to put DateFormatter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your Count confirm to Comparable:

```
class Count: NSObject, Codable, Comparable {
        static func < (lhs: Count, rhs: Count) -> Bool {
            lhs.reps < rhs.reps
        }
        
      var reps: Double
      var date = Date()
    
        init(reps: Double) {
        self.reps = reps
        super.init()
        }
    
    }   
    
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Count", for: indexPath)
        
     let item = countExercise.reps[indexPath.row]
        
      let formatter = DateFormatter()
          formatter.dateStyle = .short
          formatter.timeStyle = .short
        
                
       if let count = countExercise.reps.max(), 
              count.reps == item.reps {
                    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 26)
                } else {
                    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 26)
                }
                
          cell.textLabel?.text = item.reps.removeZerosFromEnd()
          cell.detailTextLabel?.text = formatter.string(from: item.date)
        
                return cell
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a property to your view controller to keep track of the highest `reps` count among all the `Count` objects in your array:

```swift
var highestRep: Double? {

  // We can map over all reps to "extract" each individual `reps` count.
  // This leaves us with an array of `Double` values. We can then call 
  // `max()` on it to get the highest value:

  return countExercise.reps.max{ $0.reps < $1.reps }?.reps
}

// Now that we know which is the highest number, you can format
// your cell's text accordingly, when setting up your cell:

if highestRep == item.reps {
  // Bold text
} else {
  // Regular text
}
```

The `max()` method returns an `Optional` value, so that's why the new property is of type `Double?`. In case you have an empty array, it would return `nil`.

Comment: There is no need to unwrap highestRep before comparing it

Comment: you are welcome. Btw you can avoid iterating the collection twice using max(by:) and pass a predicate to it   `countExercise.reps.max{$0.reps < $1.reps}?.reps`